# Replace \n with space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pd dataframe where I have text in a cloumn called Text.
I want to replace each newline with a space. Therefore i tried:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  df['Text']=df['Text'].str.replace('\n',"")
```

The Problem is: if the original text is written like of\nthe after applying my method i get ofthe.

Any solutions?

Comment: Think about what you have tried, and think about how you could change it to achieve what you are searching for. You should seek to understand the code you are writing...

Comment: yes, i know now that it was a stupid question because the answer is pretty obvious, but as i am new to python please excuse my not yet existing understanding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a space in the replace character:

```
df['Text']=df['Text'].str.replace('\n'," ")
```